# SoftLayer API - retrieve invoices

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am using SoftLayer_Billing_Invoice::getPdfDetailed to retrieve the latest invoice, but the file does not seem to be a binary file. How to decode that file and get it opened.

Answer (score 0):

that depends on if you are using a Softlayer client or if you are using simple REST request, using a simple REST request the response is encoded in base64 and you must decode it (you could try using this online tool http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp and export the result in a file)

Now if you are using a Sofltyer client such as Softlayer's Python or Ruby client they are using xmlrpc for the request and they uses its own data type to store that data you can see an example about that using the Python client here  [How to get "PDF" file from the binary data of SoftLayer's quote?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41932706/how-to-get-pdf-file-from-the-binary-data-of-softlayers-quote/41949599#41949599)

Regards